# Windows Azure Project is not loading

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, azure

I am having below mentioned issue when I am running The **Azure Project on Emulator**.

1. Below mentioned error popup is not coming always.
2. It's appearing Time to Time
3. Sometimes my Azure project loads as expected but sometimes not

Why ?

**My Environment as below :**

1. VS 2010 SP 1
2. MVC 2 Project
3. Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - October 2012 v1.8.51019.1603

**Error shown as below :**

[image]

**My Azure project as below:**

[image]

**Error message on IISConfigurator**

```
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000001, 2013/01/02 12:14:39.516] Started iisconfigurator with args /start
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000001, 2013/01/02 12:14:39.532] StartForeground selected. Check if an instance is already running
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000001, 2013/01/02 12:14:39.563] Starting service WAS
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000001, 2013/01/02 12:14:39.813] Starting service w3svc
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000001, 2013/01/02 12:14:39.828] Starting service apphostsvc
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000001, 2013/01/02 12:14:40.764] Setting registry key for cloud drive to path:C:\Users\sampath\AppData\Local\dftmp\wadd
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000001, 2013/01/02 12:14:40.858] IISConfigurator is running
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000006, 2013/01/02 12:14:40.998] Clean operation called over WCF interface with prefix 'deployment18('
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:11.64] Deploying sites from package path D:\PawLoyalty Module\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty.Web.Azure\csx\Debug\roles\PawLoyalty.Web with given optional destination directory 
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:11.64] Using full IIS appdomain
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:11.687] Creating site named deployment18(2790).PawLoyalty.Web.Azure.PawLoyalty.Web_IN_0_Web for modelled site name Web
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:11.687] Deploying site named deployment18(2790).PawLoyalty.Web.Azure.PawLoyalty.Web_IN_0_Web
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:11.687] Using package path D:\PawLoyalty Module\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty.Web\ which exists? True
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:11.687] Adding binding 127.255.0.0:82:www.pawloyalty.com to site deployment18(2790).PawLoyalty.Web.Azure.PawLoyalty.Web_IN_0_Web
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:12.545] Add access for appPool d3f7f918-51ee-4c8b-b113-18bdf8ff08c9 to runtime api instance deployment18(2790).PawLoyalty.Web.Azure.PawLoyalty.Web_IN_0 for SID 
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:12.794] Add access for appPool d3f7f918-51ee-4c8b-b113-18bdf8ff08c9 to site directory D:\PawLoyalty Module\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty.Web\ for SID 
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:12.794] Adding access to users IUSR and NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE to path D:\PawLoyalty Module\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty.Web\
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:13.371] Added access to users IUSR and NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE to path D:\PawLoyalty Module\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty.Web\
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:13.371] Add access to NetworkService to web.config
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:13.387] Add access for appPool d3f7f918-51ee-4c8b-b113-18bdf8ff08c9 to cloud drive directory C:\Users\sampath\AppData\Local\dftmp\wadd for SID 
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:13.387] Deploy Complete
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:13.387] Add read access to runtime base dir
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:13.387] Adding access to IIS_IUSRS to D:\PawLoyalty Module\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty.Web.Azure\csx\Debug\roles\PawLoyalty.Web\base
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000007, 2013/01/02 12:15:13.917] Added access to IIS_IUSRS to physical path D:\PawLoyalty Module\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty.Web.Azure\csx\Debug\roles\PawLoyalty.Web\base
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000010, 2013/01/02 12:15:13.964] Wait for all sites to be setup in IIS
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00005740:00000010, 2013/01/02 12:15:14.151] All sites and app pools are ready, wait for sites complete.
```

When I click **PawLoyalty.Web.Azure -> Properties -> Web** It's like below

[image]

Comment: Check %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\dftmp\IISConfiguratorLogs\IISConfigurator.log file for error messages

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson I have put that on my post please check that?

Comment: Ok, no exceptions there... I you set PawLoyalty.Web as startup project and run it(F5). Does it work then? If you restart the azure emulator when you get this error and try againg, dows that solve it?

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson My PawLoyalty.Web project is working.Restart of emulator does not solve my issue.Another thing should I get above log details when I am having that issue or at any time (even when working Azure moments.B'cos it's log it should have keep older record also Know? Am I right ?).

Comment: You should have todays logs in it. We were hoping to get an exception when you tried to start your service. Btw, can you start it with shift+F5? Do you have IISEXpress selected if you right click PawLoyalty.Web.Azure -> Properties -> Web?

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson What should I start By using shift+F5 ? I have updated my post for your 2nd question.Please check That.

Comment: I was curious to see if you can start it without active debugger. It would make the problem smaller. However, I provided an answer for you. Almost certain this will work :)

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson Could you give more details about what you meant By "I was curious to see if you can start it without active debugger" ?

Comment: In other words-> The problem is that it cant attach the debugger when you try to run your azure project. Does it run on the emulator without the debug mode(ie shift F5)? However, I provided a solution in my answer below. Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable IISExpress and try again. If it does not work, check the logs mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Yes.You're correct.When I changed Local Development Server (as a Use IIS Express) My problem vanished.Thanks for your support.